# Aggregating daily data to monthly data SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate

I have a list of road incidents that vary based on type (breakdown, crashes, fire, hazard etc.). Currently I have them as daily data but I need to aggregate it into monthly data. A month is defined as every 30 days, so if I have a date range from 03/03/2021 - 27/05/2021, the expected output would be:

| Month | Date Start | Date End | Type | Incident Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 03.03.21 | 01.04.21 | Breakdown | 20 |
| 2 | 02.04.21 | 01.05.21 | Breakdown | 30 |
| 3 | 02.05.21 | 31.05.21 | Breakdown | 55 |
| 1 | 03.03.21 | 01.04.21 | Crash | 20 |
| 2 | 02.04.21 | 01.05.21 | Crash | 30 |
| 3 | 02.05.21 | 31.05.21 | Crash | 55 |

Note how in the Date End, I have gone beyond the end date range (27/05/2021) and included data from 28/05/2021 - 31/05/2021 in order to complete the month and include 30 days.

Input table

| Incident Date | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 03.03.21 | Breakdown |
| 04.03.21 | Crash |
| 05.03.21 | Fire |
| 06.03.21 | Breakdown |
| 07.03.21 | Breakdown |

Etc.

Comment: Can you share a sample of the input table?

Comment: why can't you select month, start, end, type and sum incident count and group by month, start, end type?

Comment: The months may contain data from other months, the issue is month is defined as 30 days from the start date, and the true end date may exceed the end date of what has been specified, for example in the above example even the specified end date was 27/05/2021 the true end date was 31/05/2021.

Comment: This seems a bit odd calling your 30-day span/range a "month" - so if the first day of the date range happened to be the 15th then every "month" starts and ends based on this also? Two reports of the same data with slightly different ranges can classify the *same* data as two *different* "months"??

Comment: Thats correct, it is odd I agree but it is a one-time thing

Comment: What is the start date of your year ? How many months do you need ?

Answer (score 0):

A solution consist in building a calendar with a recusive CTE query, and join this calendar to the incident table and perform a `GROUP BY`.

Here is a complete sample with data generation (at the end):

```
DECLARE @startDate date = DATEFROMPARTS(2021, 3, 3);
DECLARE @endDate date = DATEFROMPARTS(2021, 12, 30);

WITH dateRange AS
(
    SELECT  1 AS MonthNumber,
            @startDate AS MonthStartDate,
            IIF(DATEADD(DAY, 29, @startDate) > @endDate, @endDate, DATEADD(DAY, 29, @startDate))  AS MonthEndDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  1 + dra.MonthNumber,
            DATEADD(DAY, 1, dra.MonthEndDate),
            IIF(DATEADD(DAY, 29, DATEADD(DAY, 1, dra.MonthEndDate)) > @endDate, @endDate, DATEADD(DAY, 29, DATEADD(DAY, 1, dra.MonthEndDate)))  AS MonthEndDate
    FROM dateRange dra
    WHERE dra.MonthEndDate < @endDate AND dra.MonthNumber < 100
)
SELECT  dra.MonthNumber,
        dra.MonthStartDate,
        dra.MonthEndDate,
        inc.IncidentType,
        COUNT(1) AS IncidentCount
FROM #incident inc
        INNER JOIN dateRange dra ON inc.IncidentDate BETWEEN dra.MonthStartDate AND dra.MonthEndDate
GROUP BY dra.MonthNumber, dra.MonthStartDate, dra.MonthEndDate, inc.IncidentType;
```

Data generation:

```
CREATE TABLE #incident
(
    IncidentDate    date NOT NULL,
    IncidentType    varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #incident
VALUES  (DATEFROMPARTS(2021, 3, 3), 'Breakdown'),
        (DATEFROMPARTS(2021, 3, 4), 'Crash'),
        (DATEFROMPARTS(2021, 3, 5), 'Fire'),
        (DATEFROMPARTS(2021, 3, 6), 'Breakdown'),
        (DATEFROMPARTS(2021, 3, 7), 'Breakdown'),
        (DATEFROMPARTS(2021, 3, 7), 'Breakdown'),
        (DATEFROMPARTS(2021, 3, 8), 'Crash'),
        (DATEFROMPARTS(2021, 3, 9), 'Fire'),
        
        (DATEFROMPARTS(2021, 5, 3), 'Breakdown'),
        (DATEFROMPARTS(2021, 5, 4), 'Crash'),
        (DATEFROMPARTS(2021, 5, 5), 'Fire'),
        (DATEFROMPARTS(2021, 5, 6), 'Breakdown'),
        (DATEFROMPARTS(2021, 5, 7), 'Breakdown'),
        (DATEFROMPARTS(2021, 5, 7), 'Breakdown'),
        (DATEFROMPARTS(2021, 5, 8), 'Crash'),
        (DATEFROMPARTS(2021, 5, 9), 'Fire'),

        (DATEFROMPARTS(2021, 7, 3), 'Breakdown'),
        (DATEFROMPARTS(2021, 7, 4), 'Crash'),
        (DATEFROMPARTS(2021, 7, 5), 'Fire'),
        (DATEFROMPARTS(2021, 7, 6), 'Breakdown'),
        (DATEFROMPARTS(2021, 7, 7), 'Breakdown'),
        (DATEFROMPARTS(2021, 7, 7), 'Breakdown'),
        (DATEFROMPARTS(2021, 7, 8), 'Crash'),
        (DATEFROMPARTS(2021, 7, 9), 'Fire');
```

Isolated calendar creation:

```
DECLARE @startDate date = DATEFROMPARTS(2021, 3, 3);
DECLARE @endDate date = DATEFROMPARTS(2021, 12, 30);

WITH dateRange AS
(
    SELECT  1 AS MonthNumber,
            @startDate AS MonthStartDate,
            IIF(DATEADD(DAY, 29, @startDate) > @endDate, @endDate, DATEADD(DAY, 29, @startDate))  AS MonthEndDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  1 + dr.MonthNumber,
            DATEADD(DAY, 1, dr.MonthEndDate),
            IIF(DATEADD(DAY, 29, DATEADD(DAY, 1, dr.MonthEndDate)) > @endDate, @endDate, DATEADD(DAY, 29, DATEADD(DAY, 1, dr.MonthEndDate)))  AS MonthEndDate
    FROM dateRange dr
    WHERE dr.MonthEndDate < @endDate AND dr.MonthNumber < 100
)
SELECT  MonthNumber,
        MonthStartDate,
        MonthEndDate
FROM dateRange;
```